# Can't jump into nginx docker container on startup

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, tty, docker-exec

I can start and exec into a ubuntu docker container using this command:

```
$ docker container run -it --rm ubuntu
root@ded56bdb6f95:/#
```

However, I get a blank console when I attempt to do the same for an nginx server (though it does print the logs here):

```
$ docker container run -it -p 81:80 --rm nginx
# this is blank
```

I can exec in by running an additional command while the nginx server is runnning:

```
docker container exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
root@6270d301d3fd:/#
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or if this is the expected behavior?

Comment: Can you add output of: docker ps -a 
I think you have the wrong image name

Comment: You should generally imagine a container as a wrapper around a single process.  In the same way that it doesn't really make sense to get a shell in your Chrome/Firefox browser, it doesn't make sense to get a shell in an Nginx server either, and you should reserve interactive shells and `docker exec` for debugging and not day-to-day use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just need to add the name of the shell (e.g. `bash` or `sh`) to the end of the docker run command:

```
docker container run -it -p 81:80 --rm nginx bash
```